# Django: Query Database

Tags: python, django

Here's my model,

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

How can I filter out the Questions asked in last 14 hours?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=14)
results = Question.objects.filter(timestamp__lt=time_threshold)
```

by docs [__lt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#lt) means less than.

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate instead of plagiarising the accepted answer.